# Snort false positive?

Tags: attacks, ids, buffer-overflow, snort

I've set up snort and am configuring it for my network.  I have one vpn server making a connection to my dns/AD server.  This connection sets off:

```
GPL SHELLCODE x86 inc ebx NOOP
```

The payload is as follows:

```
....WANG2..JFIF``..C

(1#%(:3=<9387@H\N@DWE78PmQW_bghg>Mqypdx\egc..C//cB8Bcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc..&.!..   
...}!1AQa"q2...#B..R..$3br. 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz...........................................................................    
...w!1AQaq"2.B....  #3R.br.
$4.%.&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz..........................................................................?.5mJ#M...dh.....q.=j...+/G3Y.P.@t.@#=...j..u.g...4....................iw......yq..r......ZTQ@Q@Q@
.D.6.GTD...(I5....I..b..+.ie$.)$.[8.3.@..........$..,.......=N..T....E..g.............N.@P.z........S.M7M...iF_k6..>...-...9.;.L.....B..x.9..y.h.5.w.'Q..>...._/v..9Q.`..{t.Z..i..}...P..I,.$....@..'G..q._G..E.*~..s..]..E...$...-.)L.N7m...=........tI..o...v.K...rrp.\mx......s..o&%..c.A.u.zP*....h.....Z..i.q
O.Q.......H....:...K.0#.##...q..9..Mo.?{..n...........{V..<Ek.y.$.Xv.cq.I.q..<t.|Mo.2[.2]_K...@A`I..9..6n.=kI.......G...,.Z..MJ..J.4.n..    RIS8.m...}I....x..M........e..D     c.s.^._.......O.st.3..$...;N....zus.;..B........J..u[b.k.`.aAU....4k..._hze....VtdV
2.......}[..d..|#kb.N#R.H
..o............E
.>?......b3yx'.'9..A..\A.......B...A#...H.D.~.go4...y.|.W(x...o.cD..."*.231..a.......u...[uxT..p....\...:..(u..1L.[...3.u...Y...>..D..NR".........=}.@..._...V.....$..N2.x..0x.5...C....sw...."(u...r..'..S..+{.=z....._&2@....u
.g......C{....s.D.!eYA#..Bh/K.K..N...S.8.
@......B.....................9....}.l..b..VI.x...M.Oane...l{..8..6...Cq...I......7......?.a...}.....O.|1._..<u7.,/b...t.Z[.C..P..9...#...9.
...a.....6.]A...he..z.9=q...lol<..q,.om3.d...(p..=y.M.O.,.....j..5....G.M6.2/#FT`d....06d.w~5:...>....a.3(_-O..
```

**My Question**

How do you determine if this is a file transfer or actual shellcode trying to do a buffer overflow like the rule database [says](http://rootedyour.com/snortsid?sid=1:1390)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NOOPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_slide) are the tip-off for the snort rules. A file transfer is likely not to have NOP slides, but in this case, it might be a false positive:

```
WANG2..JFIF
```

What you may have here is a ping from one Windows machine to another. Part of the ping payload is a jpg of the word: Microsoft.

This type of traffic has triggered other people to [be](http://packetfu.org/2003/08/wang2-jfif-snort-traffic.html) [suspicious](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/wierd-icmp-activity-t1726372.html), [as](http://blog.joeware.net/2007/06/05/910/) [well](http://www.wfu.edu/~steinsj5/work/icmp.html).

But, it would be nice to have the packet trace instead of the ASCII translation of the hex.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't have a complete answer for you, keep in mind that the rule on this one is just a string of "C" in ASCII or 0x43. so it's fairly inaccurate.

Snort Rule that found this was:

```
alert ip $EXTERNAL_NET $SHELLCODE_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"SHELLCODE x86 inc ebx NOOP"; content:"CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
; classtype:shellcode-detect; sid:1390; rev:5;)
```

Example alert file from snort:

```
[**] [1:1390:5] SHELLCODE x86 inc ebx NOOP [**]
[Classification: Executable code was detected] [Priority: 1] 
01/15-17:32:16.249189 192.168.2.101:3128 -> 192.168.2.103:57310
TCP TTL:64 TOS:0x0 ID:22656 IpLen:20 DgmLen:1500 DF
***A**** Seq: 0xC2797B70  Ack: 0x11FE472E  Win: 0x8B  TcpLen: 32
TCP Options (3) => NOP NOP TS: 59640418 25088619
```